# How can I implement a method which returns a string by passing an integer, without having lot of if statements?

Tags: java, if-statement, simplify

I need some advice. I have a method like this :

```
Private String myMethod(int a_var) {
    String l_myString = "Hello";
    if (a_var == 1) {
        l_myString = "Hi"; 
    }
    if (a_var == 2) {
        l_myString = "Hey";
    }
    return l_myString
}
```

etc... I have ten if statement like this, and honestly i have no idea on how to simplify this. I was expecting to find how to do this on the web but it seems that i'm not enought accurate on my search, so if i can have some advices!

Comment: _ten if statement like_ post em all. _how to simplify this_ what did you actually mean by *simplify*?

Comment: does [switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) help?

Comment: by the way, in cases like that, also add `else`s, to skip unnecessary checks, or add multiple `return`s immediately, if no further processing is applied.

Comment: @DanielV, the problem in my opinion with switch, is the fact that it don't really reduce the numbers of line, i prefer use a list.

Comment: @SebastienMURE you are right, but sometimes for maintenance is more readable to use switch, because you never know who is going to inherit your code, I agree the list approach is very nice, switch is just an option, means to an end!!

Comment: @DanielV, I agree with that too huhu, thanks for the advice, i will discuss this with my intership mentor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `switch`, or a map (only if the output is **constant**) depending on the context :

**switch**

```
switch (a_var) {
   case 1: return "Hey";
   case 2: return "Hi";
   ...
   default: return "Hello";
}
```

**map** :

```
// somewhere in the class
private static final Map<Integer, String> SOME_NAME = new HashMap<>();
static {
    SOME_NAME.put(1, "Hey");
    SOME_NAME.put(2, "Hi");
}

private String myMethod(int a_var) {
    return SOME_NAME.getOrDefault(a_var, "Hello");
}
```

Comment: I'd like the use of the HashMap too, but i should have precised that i'm in work placement, and this is java 1.7 here (my bad for not saying this), so there's is not getOrDefault. I will have to make a few lines more.

Answer (score 6):

If your method is build the way it is shown, and the values are predefined then you could also work with an array;

```
final static String[] output = {"Hey", "Ho", "Hallo", "Hi"};
...
public String method(int input) {
    return input-1 >= 0 && input-1 < output.length ? output[input-1] : "hello";
}
```

Edit : making sure output is in range

Comment: Ok for your edit, but you are still assuming all the indexes are consecutive, and still allocating the array each time

Comment: @Dici yeah i changed the allocation, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Original question implies 1-indexing... you're implying 0-indexing... in your use of the lookup array...

Comment: @Adam Thanks, didn´t notice that one

Comment: Well, it works pretty great for me, and i think it's easily understandable (i'm on work placement and they ask me for simple code and as little lines as possible. Thank you by the way, and sorry for my bad english. Edit : The 0-indexing is not a problem for me.

Answer (score 5):

If you can make a predefined *mapping* between numbers and greetings, you can do:

```
public class Greeter {
    private Map<Integer, String> mapping = new TreeMap<Integer, String>() {{
        put(1, "Hi");
        put(2, "Hey");
    }};

    public String myMethod(int number) {
        String greet = mapping.get(number);
        return mapping != null ? mapping : "Hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: Real unrequired complication, I may say. Especially the instance block.

Comment: @MouseEvent I don't agree. What is complicated with this code ? It was one of the possibilities I thought about too

Answer (score 2):

A [switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) case is the better choice for you instead of multiple `if`. Go for it.

Comment: Interesting how well, psychology works... :). Boy, I decided to upvote it just because it was downvoted.

Comment: At the beginning the answer was ok, but now with the other answers I think a bit more precisions would make it better looking

Answer (score 1):

First of all... clean your code, format it and use correct notation.

After, use `switch()`

```
private String myMethod(int aVar) {
    String myString;
    switch(aVar) {
    case 1:
        myString = "Hi"; 
    break;
    case 2:
        myString = "Hey"; 
    break;
    default:
        myString = "Hello";
    break;
    }

    return myString 
}
```

Comment: I just think of the `default` and wonder what the second line does, in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Various choices depending on performance / number of cases etc.

### Simplify your existing structure to use else if

```
    String l_myString = "Hello";
    if (a_var == 1) {
        l_myString = "Hi";
    } else if (a_var == 2) {
        l_myString = "Hey";
    }
    return l_myString;
```

### Use a case statement

```
String l_myString;
switch (a_var) {
case 1:
    l_myString = "Hi";
    break;
case 2:
    l_myString = "Hey";
    break;
default:
    l_myString = "Hello";
    break;
}
return l_myString;
```

### Use some kind of lookup, e.g. an array.

```
private static final String[] RESULTS = new String[] { "Hi", "Hey" };

private String arrayCache(int a_var) {  
    return a_var >= 1 && a_var <= RESULTS.length ? RESULTS[a_var - 1] : "Hello";
}
```

### Define your values externally in a configuration file

```
private class Greeting {
    private Properties properties;

    public Greeting() throws IOException {
        properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
    }

    public String myMethod(int a_var) {
        String l_myString = properties.getProperty("value." + a_var);
        if (l_myString == null) {
            l_myString = properties.getProperty("default");
        }
        return l_myString;
    }
}
```

config.properties

```
default=Hello
value.1=Hi
value.2=Hey
```

Comment: It's not a cache if you allocate it every time you call the method

Comment: Thanks fixed, was too quick to post.